# check boxes not aligned in div

Tags: html, checkbox, vertical-alignment

i have a form on  a div with check boxes, the check boxes are to low in relationship to the line of the text,

what is missing to make it align vertically?,, thanks!

```
<div id="dialog-form2" title="Titulo">
<p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
<form>
<fieldset>
<label for="name">Your name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="email">Your email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="email">Your phone number</label>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
<label for="password">Your Member Number</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-  content ui-corner-all" />

<br>
Enquiry<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Milk"> I would like to r <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter">I need a h <br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter">Please email me with offer details<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter">Please call me to discuss offer<br>  
<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Butter">Other?<br>  

</fieldset>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to answer this without knowing what your style sheet is looking like.  Even your font / font size will affect this to some degree.  For instance, just pasting your code into a blank html file and bringing it up in a browser alignment is slightly off because it's using Times for the font for me, but then if i change the body font to arial it lines up great.  Just having only this snipped with no associated css makes it hard to answer the question as clearly as you might need.